# Does Java time correctly handle Michigan's timezone/DST history?

Tags: java-time

I stumbled upon the image below and wondered: **Will Java time correctly reflect Michigan's chronology of time observance?**

[Image source](http://s.mlive.com/cu03ozU)

*Note: that the dates for general U.S. changes do not necessarily line up with Michigan's adoption dates for those changes.*

[image: Chronology of Time Observance in Michigan]

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, Michigan time history is meticulously handled by Java time

I am extremely impressed with the precision and sophistication of Java time in its handling of `America/Detroit` and `America/Menominee`'s time history. It appears that each of the cases described above are handled correctly. I sincerely applaud the developers of Joda and Java time, this is an awesome display of work.

### Test Case

Below is a set of test cases to exercise the scenarios in the image above. Note that rough dates are used for simplicity here yet the library is capable of greater precision.

```java
@Test
public void dstHistoryInMichigan() {
  String detroitMeanTime = "-05:32:11";
  String menomineeMeanTime = "-05:50:27";
  String cst = "-06:00";
  String cdt = "-05:00";
  String centralWarTime = "-05:00";
  String est = "-05:00";
  String edt = "-04:00";
  String easternWarTime = "-04:00";

  assertThat(detroit(1883, 7, 30)).as("Detroit 1883").isEqualTo(detroitMeanTime);
  assertThat(menominee(1883, 7, 30)).as("Menominee 1883").isEqualTo(menomineeMeanTime);
  assertThat(detroit(1905, 2, 20)).as("Detroit 1905").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(menominee(1905, 2, 20)).as("Menominee 1905").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(detroit(1923, 1, 1)).as("Detroit 1923").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(menominee(1923, 1, 1)).as("Menominee 1923").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(detroit(1937, 7, 30)).as("Detroit 1937").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(menominee(1937, 7, 30)).as("Menominee 1937").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(detroit(1944, 7, 30)).as("Detroit 1944").isEqualTo(easternWarTime);
  assertThat(menominee(1944, 7, 30)).as("Menominee 1944").isEqualTo(centralWarTime);
  assertThat(detroit(1946, 7, 30)).as("Detroit 1946").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(menominee(1946, 1, 30)).as("Menominee 1946").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(detroit(1966, 7, 30)).as("Detroit 1966").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(menominee(1966, 7, 30)).as("Menominee 1966").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(detroit(1967, 7, 30)).as("Detroit 1967").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(menominee(1967, 7, 30)).as("Menominee 1967").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(detroit(1968, 7, 30)).as("Detroit 1968").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(menominee(1968, 7, 30)).as("Menominee 1968").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(detroit(1973, 1, 30)).as("Detroit Jan 1973").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(detroit(1973, 7, 30)).as("Detroit Summer 1973").isEqualTo(edt);
  assertThat(detroit(1974, 1, 7)).as("Detroit Jan 1974").isEqualTo(edt);
  assertThat(detroit(1974, 7, 30)).as("Detroit Summer 1974").isEqualTo(edt);
  assertThat(detroit(1974, 10, 28)).as("Detroit Fall 1974").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(menominee(1974, 7, 30)).as("Menominee Summer 1974").isEqualTo(cdt);
  assertThat(menominee(1974, 10, 28)).as("Menominee Fall 1974").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(detroit(1975, 3, 5)).as("Detroit March 1975").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(detroit(1975, 4, 28)).as("Detroit April 1975").isEqualTo(edt);
  assertThat(menominee(1975, 2, 5)).as("Menominee Feb 1975").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(menominee(1975, 4, 28)).as("Menominee April 1975").isEqualTo(cdt);
  assertThat(detroit(1985, 4, 7)).as("Detroit April 1985").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(detroit(1987, 4, 7)).as("Detroit April 1987").isEqualTo(edt);
  assertThat(menominee(1985, 4, 7)).as("Menominee April 1985").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(menominee(1987, 4, 7)).as("Menominee April 1987").isEqualTo(cdt);
  assertThat(detroit(2004, 3, 15)).as("Detroit March 2004").isEqualTo(est);
  assertThat(detroit(2007, 3, 15)).as("Detroit March 2007").isEqualTo(edt);
  assertThat(menominee(2004, 3, 15)).as("Menominee March 2004").isEqualTo(cst);
  assertThat(menominee(2007, 3, 15)).as("Menominee March 2007").isEqualTo(cdt);
}

private static final ZoneId menomineeTz = ZoneId.of("America/Menominee");
private static final ZoneId detroitTz = ZoneId.of("America/Detroit");

private String detroit(int year, int month, int day) {
  return getOffset(LocalDate.of(year, month, day), detroitTz);
}

private String menominee(int year, int month, int day) {
    return getOffset(LocalDate.of(year, month, day), menomineeTz);
}

private String getOffset(LocalDate date, ZoneId tz) {
  return date.atStartOfDay(tz).withZoneSameInstant(tz).getOffset().getId();
}
```